# Trouble with a button that calls a subroutine that uses a function

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently coding in VBA and have run into an issue.

I have created a button that calls in a number of subroutines. It runs perfectly until it reaches a subroutine that uses a function. When I run the sub in the developer tab, it runs fine; however, when I call the subroutine using a button I get this error:

"Compile Error:
Method or data member not found."

Do you know how to fix this?

Below is the subroutine and function being used:

```
Sub DiscountRate()

    'Set Dimensions
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Counter As Integer
    Dim Value As Integer
    Dim tempcount As Double

    'Set parameters
    Set SummarySheet = Sheets("Summary & Inputs")
    Set ExpectedCompSheet = Sheets("Expected Compensation")
    Set WorkYears = SummarySheet.Range("C40")
    Set DiscountSheet = Sheets("Treasury Rates")
    Set DiscountRateRange = DiscountSheet.Range("B7:L7")

    'Clear column
    ExpectedCompSheet.Range("H13:I113").Clear
    'Clear color
    ExpectedCompSheet.Range("H13:I113").Interior.Color = xlNone


    'If prejudgment interest is filled, count and fill discount rate cells
    i = 1
    For Counter = 1 To WorkYears
        If IsEmpty(ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(12 + Counter, 7)) = False Then
            ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(12 + Counter, 8).Interior.ColorIndex = 16
            ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(12 + Counter, 9).Interior.ColorIndex = 16
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next Counter

    'Create increasing range to sum fractions of years
    IncreasingRange = ExpectedCompSheet.Range(ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(12 + i, 5), _
                                              ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 5))

    'Find discount rate associated with increasing years
    For Counter = 1 To (WorkYears + 2 - i)
        IncreasingRange = ExpectedCompSheet.Range(ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(12 + i, 5), _
                                                  ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 5))
        tempcount = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(IncreasingRange)
        ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 8) = getclosest(DiscountRateRange, tempcount)
    Next Counter


    For Counter = 1 To (WorkYears + 2 - i)
        If ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 8) = 0.08 Then
            ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 8) = "1 Month"
            ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 9) = DiscountSheet.Range("B9") / 100
        ElseIf ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 8) = 0.25 Then
            ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 8) = "3 Month"
            ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 9) = DiscountSheet.Range("C9") / 100
        ElseIf ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 8) = 0.5 Then
            ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 8) = "6 Month"
            ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 9) = DiscountSheet.Range("D9") / 100
        ElseIf ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 8) = 1 Then
            ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 8) = "1 Year"
            ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 9) = DiscountSheet.Range("E9") / 100
        ElseIf ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 8) = 2 Then
            ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 8) = "2 Year"
            ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 9) = DiscountSheet.Range("F9") / 100
        ElseIf ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 8) = 3 Then
            ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 8) = "3 Year"
            ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 9) = DiscountSheet.Range("G9") / 100
        ElseIf ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 8) = 5 Then
            ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 8) = "5 Year"
            ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 9) = DiscountSheet.Range("H9") / 100
        ElseIf ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 8) = 7 Then
            ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 8) = "7 Year"
            ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 9) = DiscountSheet.Range("I9") / 100
        ElseIf ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 8) = 10 Then
            ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 8) = "10 Year"
            ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 9) = DiscountSheet.Range("J9") / 100
        ElseIf ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 8) = 20 Then
            ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 8) = "20 Year"
            ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 9) = DiscountSheet.Range("K9") / 100
        ElseIf ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 8) = 30 Then
            ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 8) = "30 Year"
            ExpectedCompSheet.Cells(11 + i + Counter, 9) = DiscountSheet.Range("L9") / 100
        End If
    Next Counter

End Sub

Function getclosest(ByVal rng As Range, tgt As Double) As Double
    t = WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)
    For Each r In rng
        u = Abs(r - tgt)
        If u < t Then
            t = u
            getclosest = r
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

I am using a button with code:

```
Sub CalculateExpectedComp()

Call Module1.ExpectedCompYear
Call Module1.ExpectedCompPeriod
Call Module1.ExpectedCompAge
Call Module1.ExpectedCompPaymentAnnual
Call Module1.ExpectedCompYearFrac
Call Module1.ExpectedCompPartialYearComp
Call Module1.PrejudgmentInterest
Call Module1.DiscountRate
Call Module1.PresentValueFactor
Call Module1.PV
Call Module1.CumulativeValue
Call Module1.Formatting

End Sub
```

The issue occurs when "Call Module1.DiscountRate" runs.

Comment: On which line does this occur? I cannot reproduce currently.

Comment: @Patrick-Jaeger: Welcome to Stack Overflow: Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question and be sure to ask a [good, clear, concise question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion),  include the code, expected behaviour, and **what is wrong** (be specific)... then we can try to help

Comment: It does not occur on a specific line. Rather, when i use the button and it gets to line "Call Module1.DiscountFactor" I have the error.

Comment: DiscountRate or DiscountFactor?

Comment: Do you have `Option Explicit` at the top of the code module? If not, add it. I see at least one undeclared variable - `r` - in that recursive function that apparently has to do with the problem. Then, put a Break Point at the line that's marked yellow / is behind the problem so that execution pauses there. Press F8 to "step" through each line of code until you hit the one that's failing.

Comment: Thanks guys. My issue is resolved.